# Can't set array value with TextView.SetText

Tags: java, android, android-studio

there is a problem with assigning values ​​to the TextView in the following code snippet:

```
public class EventHandler implements RfidEventsListener {
        // Read Event Notification
        public void eventReadNotify(RfidReadEvents e) {
            // Recommended to use new method getReadTagsEx for better performance in case of large tag population
            TagData[] myTags = reader.Actions.getReadTags(2);

            if (myTags != null) {
                for (int index = 0; index < myTags.length; index++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Tag ID " + myTags[index].getTagID());
                    **textView.setText(myTags[0].getTagID());**

                    if (myTags[index].getOpCode() == ACCESS_OPERATION_CODE.ACCESS_OPERATION_READ &&
                            myTags[index].getOpStatus() == ACCESS_OPERATION_STATUS.ACCESS_SUCCESS) {
                        if (myTags[index].getMemoryBankData().length() > 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, " Mem Bank Data " + myTags[index].getMemoryBankData());
```

I am trying to assign the value of the zero element of an array of read tags:
`textView.setText(myTags[0].getTagID());`

But nothing happens, although this line works fine and I can see the IDs of the tags read in log cat:

`Log.d(TAG, "Tag ID " + myTags[index].getTagID());`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried setting the text view in UI Thread?

```
     getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(myTags[0].getTagID());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. I did like this:

``final String myText = myTags[0].getTagID();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            textView.setText(myText);}``

Comment: Just be careful, don't use UI thread for long operations, It will lead to unresponsive UI.
Also accepting the answer will help others to find the solution for this problem more easily.